# Транслитерация

Tags: php

Вот код, который транслитерирует текст и выводит результат в браузер. Как мне сохранить результат в в файл??

```
<?php
$transliter = file_get_contents("trn.txt");
$trans = array("а"=>"a","б"=>"b","в"=>"v","г"=>"g","д"=>"d","е"=>"e", "ё"=>"yo","ж"=>"j","з"=>"z","и"=>"i","й"=>"i","к"=>"k","л"=>"l", "м"=>"m","н"=>"n","о"=>"o","п"=>"p","р"=>"r","с"=>"s","т"=>"t", "у"=>"y","ф"=>"f","х"=>"h","ц"=>"c","ч"=>"ch", "ш"=>"sh","щ"=>"sh","ы"=>"i","э"=>"e","ю"=>"u","я"=>"ya","А"=>"A","Б"=>"B","В"=>"V","Г"=>"G","Д"=>"D","Е"=>"E", "Ё"=>"Yo","Ж"=>"J","З"=>"Z","И"=>"I","Й"=>"I","К"=>"K", "Л"=>"L","М"=>"M","Н"=>"N","О"=>"O","П"=>"P", "Р"=>"R","С"=>"S","Т"=>"T","У"=>"Y","Ф"=>"F", "Х"=>"H","Ц"=>"C","Ч"=>"Ch","Ш"=>"Sh","Щ"=>"Sh", "Ы"=>"I","Э"=>"E","Ю"=>"U","Я"=>"Ya","ь"=>"","Ь"=>"","ъ"=>"","Ъ"=>"");
echo strtr("$transliter", $trans);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Простой пример создания файла(создаст, если такого не существует) из записи в него.

```
<?php
$result = '';
$fname  = './fname.txt';
$fileLink = fopen($fname, 'wb');
fwrite($fileLink, $result);
fclose($fileLink);
?>
```

Comment: итог-Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in Z:\home\localhost\www\trans.php on line 10

Comment: Вам что именно нужно сделать? Какой результат вам выведет функция strtr("$transliter", $trans); ?

Comment: транслитерированный текст из файла trn.txt

Comment: спасибо за ответ все сделал.

Answer (score 1):

Читайте про [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: тогда в файл запишется просто array

Comment: `file_put_contents('file.txt', strtr($transliter, $trans));` - так сделали?

Comment: нет не так, спасибо вам, долго мучался.