# Функция mail() php

Tags: php

Вот код php

```html
<?php

$recepient = "myemail@gmail.com";
$sitename = "mysite";

$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$text = trim($_POST["text"]);
$country = trim($_POST["country"]);
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);

$message = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
$country $phone $text

</body>
</html>

";
$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $name <$email>");
```

После него мне приходит сообщение такого содержания 
От:адрес моего хостинга
Сообщение: austria 063-111-11-11 такой то текст

После выполнения такого кода (взят из документации php https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

```html
<?php
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "HTML email";


$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$text = trim($_POST["text"]);
$country = trim($_POST["country"]);
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email </title>
</head>
<body>
$phone  $text $country
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <$email>' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Приходит вообще пустой e-mail.
Почему так происходит если классы одинаковые.
Как мне сделать чтобы приходило не 
austria, а Австрия
чтобы в отправитель можно было поставить переменную с e-mail и чтобы стилизовать сообщение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такие заголовки:

```
$headers = 'From: <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" .
        'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
        'Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8';
```

Обверните также переменные в кавычки например

```
<body>".$phone."<br>".$text."<br>".$country."</body>
```

---

Касательно `austria => Австрия` здесь нужна транслитерация например [Транслитерация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/20377/191404)

А если транслитерация не нужна и это будет просто список стран, тогда можно использовать такой массив:

```
$country = trim($_POST["country"]);

$countries = ['austria' => 'Австрия', 'germania' => 'Германия'];

$message = $phone."<br>".$text."<br>".$countries[$country];
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Кавычки помогли.

Мне не нужна транслетизация. Мне нужно просто написать переменные. Типо 'austria' => 'Австрия' и потом чтобы оно заменяло. Как это сделать?

Comment: @Dima добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все работает. А как можно украсить имейл? Поменять цвет шрифта например. Вернее можно ли как то css подключить? Я пробовал <link> но сразу php ломается.

Comment: Насколько знаю в письмах используются инлайновые стили т.е. `<style>div{color:#666;}</style>` или `<div style=\"color: #666;\">".$phone."</div>`

Comment: Если ответ принят, можете кликнуть галочку ;)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все работает. Что бы я без Вас делал =)

Comment: Но имейте ввиду что если человек введет в поле не a**u**stria а например a**v**stria то нужно и такой вариант в массиве учесть. Разве что там не input а выпадающий список select

Comment: У меня там select. Спасибо.